# Using multiple location fields in ElasticSearch + Django-Haystack

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack and ElasticSearch to index Stores.

Until now, each store had one lat,long coordinate pair; we had to change this to represent the fact that one store can deliver products to very different regions (disjunct) I've added up to ten locations (lat,long pairs) to them.

When using one location field everything was working fine and I got right results. Now, with multiple location fields, I can't get any results, not even the previuos one, for the same user and store coordinates.

My Index is as following:

```
class StoreIndex(indexes.SearchIndex,indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True,
                         template_name='search/indexes/store/store_text.txt')
    location0 = indexes.LocationField()
    location1 = indexes.LocationField()   
    location2 = indexes.LocationField()
    location3 = indexes.LocationField()
    location4 = indexes.LocationField()
    location5 = indexes.LocationField()
    location6 = indexes.LocationField()
    location7 = indexes.LocationField()
    location8 = indexes.LocationField()
    location9 = indexes.LocationField()

    def get_model(self):
        return Store

    def prepare_location0(self, obj):
        # If you're just storing the floats...
        return "%s,%s" % (obj.latitude, obj.longitude)

    # .....   up to prepare_location9
    def prepare_location9(self, obj):
        # If you're just storing the floats...
        return "%s,%s" % (obj.latitude_9, obj.longitude_9)
```

Is this the correct way to build my index?

From elasticsearch I get this mapping information:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/stores/_mapping?pretty=True
{
  "stores" : {
    "modelresult" : {
      "properties" : {
    "django_id" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "location0" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location1" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location2" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location3" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location4" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location5" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location6" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location7" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location8" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "location9" : {
      "type" : "geo_point",
      "store" : "yes"
    },
    "text" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "analyzer" : "snowball",
      "store" : "yes",
      "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
    }
  }
  } 
 }
}
```

Then, I try to query this way:

```
sqs0 = SearchQuerySet().dwithin('location0', usuario, max_dist).distance('location0',usuario).using('stores')
```

where:

**usuario**  is a Point instance representing the user trying to find stores near his position and

**max_dist** is a D instance.

If I query directly, using curl I got no results, too.

Here is the result of quering using curl with multiple location fields:

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/stores/modelresult/_search?pretty=true -d '{  "query" : { "match_all": {} },  "filter" : {"geo_distance" : { "distance" : "6km", "location0" : { "lat" : -23.5,  "lon" : -46.6 } } } } '
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
  "total" : 0,
  "max_score" : null,
  "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

If comment out the fields location1-9 from the StoreIndex class everything works fine, but if I leave them to get  multiple location points, I get no results for the same query (user position). This happens for the same query, in django as directly, using curl. That is, if I have only one location (say location0), both queries returns correct results. With more locations (location0-9), both queries didn't give any results.

Here's the results of quering directly using curl with only one location field:

```
 $ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/stores/modelresult/_search?pretty=true -d '{     "query" : { "match_all": {} },  "filter" : {"geo_distance" : { "distance" : "6km", "location0" : { "lat" : -23.5,  "lon" : -46.6 } } } } '
{
"took" : 3,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
  "total" : 5,
  "successful" : 5,
  "failed" : 0
 },
"hits" : {
  "total" : 9,
  "max_score" : 1.0,
  "hits" : [ {
    "_index" : "stores",
    "_type" : "modelresult",
    "_id" : "store.store.110",
    "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"django_ct": "store.store", "text": "RESULT OF THE SEARCH \n\n", "django_id": "110", "id": "store.store.110", "location0": "-23.4487554,-46.58912"}
  },
  lot's of results here
   ]
  }
 }
```

Of course, I rebuild_index after any change in StoreIndex.

Any help on how to get multiple location fields working with elasticsearch and django?

PS.: I've cross posted this question on Django-Haystack and ElasticSearch Google Groups.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elasticsearch/85fg7vdCBBU/discussion

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-haystack/m2A3_SF8-ls/discussion

Thanks in advance

Mário

Comment: Can you show how the record looks like in the case with multiple locations by retrieving it: curl http://localhost:9200/stoes/modelresult/store.store.128

Comment: Here it's; didn't looks OK! Seems it's not being indexed at all!
What can be going wrong?
`$ curl localhost:9200/stores/modelresult/store.store.110?pretty=true 
  "_index" : "stores",
  "_type" : "modelresult",
  "_id" : "store.store.110",
  "exists" : false
}`